# I'm struggling to get this jquery slide down and up to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The div I'm animating in jquery is supposed to slide out to expand the width. I've gotten the width animation to work but after adding the slideDown and up code nothing works, the way it should work is:

Enquiries should be clicked and it expands and after it expands the. For slides down and when its clicked again, first the fork slides up and then the ENQUIRIES- shown goes back to its original width.

I'm not sure where my codes gone wrong as I'm new to jquery and java script. THANK YOU FOR ANY HELP!

```js
//-----------ENQUIRY-FORM----------

$('#enquiry-shown').click(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    width: "950px",
    borderRadius: "0px"
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#enquiry-form').slideDown('slow');
  }, 1000);

  function() {
    if ($('#enquiry-form').is("visible") {
        $('#enquiry-form').slideUp("slow");

        else($('#enquiry-form').is("hidden") {
          $('#enquiry-form ').slideDown("slow");
        });

      });
  };

});
```

```css
/*--------ENQUIRIES---------*/

#enquiry-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#enquiry-shown {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 210px;
  border: solid 1px #d8d8d8;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#enquiry-name {
  font-family: "calibri light";
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

#enq-arrowdown {
  width: 25px;
  height: 16px;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 19px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

#enquiry-form {
  width: 950px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #d8d8d8;
  border-right: solid 1px #d8d8d8;
  border-left: solid 1px #d8d8d8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="enquiry-container">
  <div id="enquiry-shown">
    <h2 id="enquiry-name">Enquiries</h2>
    <img id="enq-arrowdown" src="https://www.optimaltravel.ca/images/arrow.png">
  </div>
  <div id="enquiry-form">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something is wrong with the stack snippet. It throws `{ "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (", "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js", "lineno": 77, "colno": 11 }`. I'm not sure whether this error was in your original post or was it introduced by the edit.

Comment: It's the original, like I said I've gone wrong somewhere and I'm unsure how to fix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed i few things in your js code, i used a class to define the condition when to slideup or down

**See the result:**

```js
//-----------ENQUIRY-FORM----------

$('#enquiry-shown').click(function() {

  var current = $(this)

  if ($('#enquiry-shown').hasClass("active")) {

    $('#enquiry-form').slideUp('slow', function() {
      current.animate({
        width: "210px",
        borderRadius: "50px"
      }, 1000);
    });

    $('#enquiry-shown').removeClass("active");


  } else {
    current.animate({
      width: "100%",
      borderRadius: "0px"
    }, 1000, function() {
      $('#enquiry-form').slideDown('slow');
    });

    $('#enquiry-shown').addClass("active");
  }


});
```

```css
/*--------ENQUIRIES---------*/

#enquiry-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#enquiry-shown {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 210px;
  border: solid 1px #d8d8d8;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#enquiry-name {
  font-family: "calibri light";
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

#enq-arrowdown {
  width: 25px;
  height: 16px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0px 20px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 1s;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

#enquiry-form {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #d8d8d8;
  border-right: solid 1px #d8d8d8;
  border-left: solid 1px #d8d8d8;
}

#enquiry-shown.active img {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="enquiry-container">
  <div id="enquiry-shown">
    <h2 id="enquiry-name">Enquiries</h2>
    <img id="enq-arrowdown" src="https://www.optimaltravel.ca/images/arrow.png">
  </div>
  <div id="enquiry-form">
    This is the enquiry form
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this helped a lot!

Comment: @AbuN2286 i improved my answer .. you can use the callback of the functions animate and sildeUp/donw to synchronize between them..take a look

Comment: You genius!  I was just going to comment if you could help  me with that, I'm not so experienced in java script especially callbacks and so thank you very much

Comment: The only thing left to do is turn the arrow image around.  else if$("#enquiry-form ").is(':visible')){
   $('#enq-arrowdown').css({height: 'transformY(180deg)'}) 
  
  } I added this but nothing

Comment: @AbuN2286 its done take a look at my edit... this can be done with just css using the active class

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if u want to achieve this effect, but try this and give me feedback:

```
$('#enquiry-shown').click(function() {

  if($('#enquiry-form').is(':visible')){
    $('#enquiry-form').slideUp('slow', function(){
      $('#enquiry-shown').animate({
        width: "210px",
        borderRadius: "50px"
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
  else if($('#enquiry-form').is(':hidden')){
    $('#enquiry-shown').animate({
      width: "950px",
      borderRadius: "0px"
    }, 1000, function(){
      $('#enquiry-form').slideDown('slow');
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of syntax errors such as incorrectly matched brackets, missing parenthesis, missing function name, and using else when you should use else if.
When you fix all of them it looks like your click function already has some of your intended functionality.

Next I'd suggest removing the setTimeout in favor of jQuery's animate end handler, which you use by attaching a function to most animations.

Lastly you should refactor your code a little. I don't think `is('visible')` does what you think it does, but luckily there's a slideToggle method that does do what you want pretty easily.

Your click handler then needs to consider cases when the menu is already open and when it's not open and then act accordingly. For that you might consider using [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) and then checking which class it is with [hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)  before deciding what animation to perform.

```js
//-----------ENQUIRY-FORM----------

$('#enquiry-shown').click(function() {
  
  if(!$(this).hasClass('closed')){ // if the form is not closed
    $(this).animate({ // animate the form to open state
      width: "950px",
      borderRadius: "0px",
    }, 1000, ()=>{ 
      $("#enquiry-form").slideToggle() 
    }); 
  }else{ // if the form is closed animate in reverse order
    $("#enquiry-form").slideToggle(
      ()=>{
        $(this).animate({
          width : "210px",
          borderRadius : "50px"
        }, 1000);
      }
     )
  }
  $(this).toggleClass('closed'); // toggle the class

});
```

```css
/*--------ENQUIRIES---------*/

#enquiry-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#enquiry-shown {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 210px;
  border: solid 1px #d8d8d8;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#enquiry-name {
  font-family: "calibri light";
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

#enq-arrowdown {
  width: 25px;
  height: 16px;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 19px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

#enquiry-form {
  width: 950px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #d8d8d8;
  border-right: solid 1px #d8d8d8;
  border-left: solid 1px #d8d8d8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="enquiry-container">
  <div id="enquiry-shown">
    <h2 id="enquiry-name">Enquiries</h2>
    <img id="enq-arrowdown" src="https://www.optimaltravel.ca/images/arrow.png">
  </div>
  <div id="enquiry-form">
    <div> Hello I am a form </div>
  </div>
</div>
```